# a Mac OsX ROS that woks with Xcode 4.5.2 and Python 2.7.x or newer

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Why does ROS have to install/compile using python2.6 (py26) ?
Mac OsX 10.7 (Lion) comes with python 2.7.3, and python 2.6 is unavailable anymore: At least when 2.7 is installed by default with the OS X; the 2.6 libraries are unavailable in usr/local/lib but 2.7 are there [instead?]. So when I follow the Mac OsX guide lines to install ROS , I am facing the obligation to install py26-yaml, and the compile comes using the python 2.7 existing in the system, which results in a compilation/linking where libraries from 2.7 are looked for in the wrong places.

Also, because of that 'confusion', the PATH indicates something while the exe and libraries are elsewhere, most likely in 2 different places. This shows in compilation that there is a mix of python2.6 use and unfound libraries of python 2.7 or versi- verca.

Does there exist a way to Install/compile ROS ROS, properly, using python2.7.x or newer; and the proper gcc compiler that comes with codeX?

Could you think of a packaged solution (dmg like) where everything needed could be put nicely together?

Thank you for guiding me with this matter at your earliest and kind convenience.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50132/a-mac-osx-ros-that-woks-with-xcode-4.5.2-and-python-2.7.x-or-newer/) by [romwalker](https://answers.ros.org/users/3762/romwalker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-12-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Current ROS distributions do not make you install python 2.6. I suggest you identify what you are trying to install and reference (link) what instructions you are following.

OSX is an experimental platform for ROS and complaining about install methods isn't useful. Also please search here on anwers.ros.org, there are lots of answers to common problems with installing Groovy, Fuerte, and even old Electric.

Once you provide some more concrete information we may be able to help. Again, OSX is a mixed bag and if you are new to ROS, maybe you should start with a Linux version first.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1